# Is this a viable way to calculate the mass of the sun?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

By measuring the Earth’s distance from the Sun, and knowing its orbital period, Newton’s Law of Universal Gravitation and Newton’s 2nd Law can I calculate the mass of the sun?

Comment: You need the mass of the earth

Comment: You actually don't need the mass of the earth.  Here's a hint: set the force due to gravity between the earth and the sun, equal to the centripetal force that the sun puts on the earth.  A bit of algebra will "drop" the mass of the earth, and a bit more algebra will allow you to separate the mass of the sun as the only unknown.

Comment: The answer is therefore :yes.

Comment: You mean Kepler's third law?

Answer (score 2):

Earth's distance from sun: $ R $

Orbital period: $T$

Sun's Mass: $M$

Earth's mass: $m$

Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation: $ F = \frac{GM m}{r^2} $

Newton’s 2nd Law: $ F = ma$

---

Okay, let's see what we can do.

[image: work done]

[image: code]

Actual mass of sun: $ 1.989 * 10^{30} kg $

Error = $ 3.37 \% $

So this approximation isn't bad! The earth's orbit is not exactly a circle, though. It is an ellipse. Newton discovered that the earth and sun both orbit around a common center of mass, dispelling the idea that one orbits around the other.

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/743391) for typesetting.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I was wondering how to do that.